# How can I get the patch informations from registry in win7 by windows API?

Tags: windows, registry

How can I get the patch informations from registry in win7 by windows API?
I want to get the  "id + name + desc + date" of all patchs.

Answer (score 0):

You can list the installed HotFixes using several ways:

**Powershell:**

```
Get-HotFix | select HotFixID, Description, InstalledOn
```

**WMI:**

```
wmic qfe get HotFixID,Description,InstalledOn
```

Both ways use the [`Win32_QuickFixEngineering`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394391(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI class to list Windows Updates, and only returns updates supplied by [Component Based Servicing (CBS)](http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2008/04/23/understanding-component-based-servicing.aspx).
Updates supplied by the Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI) or the Windows update site are not returned by `Get-Hotfix`/`Win32_QuickFixEngineering`.

Therefore if you can use [Windows Update API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387099(v=vs.85).aspx) with powershell to list **all updates**:

```
$session = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
$searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$searcher.Search("IsInstalled=1").Updates | ft -a Date,Title,Description
```

**Registry:**
You can enumarate keys on this location `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages` and then check the (string) value `InstallClient` for the `"WindowsUpdateAgent"`.

You can enumerate the keys using the Windows API functions which deals with [registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875(v=vs.85).aspx). Here's an [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724256(v=vs.85).aspx) from MSDN.

---

The Windows Update API is the recommended way by Microsoft, so you better give it a try.

Comment: But... I just want to use the Windows API to scan the registry for patches.